# Row height expanding in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have been working on this for hours and refined my problem down. Now I'm facing this funny behavior where the gap between the two rows increases as the screen width decreases.

I feel defeated and am open to redoing it completely if there are better ways to implement this design.

Design that I am trying to create:

[image: Design that I am trying to create]

My current progress:

```css
.grid2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 90rem;
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%
}

.blurb-text {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #000;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 5;
  outline: 1px solid green;
  margin: 100px 0 0 50px;
}

.Jumbotext-1 {
  /*border: 2px solid red;*/
  font-size: 156px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  outline: 1px solid green;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 5;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

.Jumbotext-2 {
  font-size: 156px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  outline: 1px solid green;
  margin: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .Jumbotext-1 {
    font-size: calc(156px + 6 * ((100vw - 320px) / 680));
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .Jumbotext-1 {
    font-size: 156px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .Jumbotext-2 {
    font-size: calc(156px + 6 * ((100vw - 320px) / 680));
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .Jumbotext-2 {
    font-size: 156px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .blurb-text {
    font-size: calc(36px + 6 * ((100vw - 320px) / 680));
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .blurb-text {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid2">
  <div class="Jumbotext-1">Deliver a unique</div>
  <div class="Jumbotext-2">experience</div>
  <div class="blurb-text">
    We can work together today<br> to create an exceptional product<br> that screams to the world,<br> I belong to you.
  </div>
</div>
```

I really need some help with this, thank you for your time and consideration!

Comment: You've created two `1fr` rows. But what's the height of the container?

Comment: I haven't set a height for the container, setting one hasn't helped either...

Comment: Well, the `fr` unit distributes extra space in the container. If you don't have a height defined, then the container takes the content height (`height: auto`), and there's no extra space. So `fr` doesn't work.

Comment: okay setting the height for the rows did help. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough revision with CSS Grid:

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0er8tcok/)

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 10vw);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, auto);
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}

span:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  font-size: 10vw;
  align-self: end;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 1 / 6;
  font-size: 10vw;
}

span:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 6 / -1;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 3em;
  font-family: georgia;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Deliver a unique</span>
  <span>experience</span>
  <span>We can work together today<br>to create an exceptional product<br>that screams to the world:<br><br><strong>I belong to you.</strong></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I'm going through it to see what I missed. Thank you so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

This looks more like a candidate for using float.

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1040px;
}

.blurb-text {
  font-size: 36px;
  float: right;
  width: 35%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.Jumbotext-1 {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 120px;
  line-height: 0.9;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  margin: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

.u-b {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="Jumbotext-1">Deliver a unique experience</div>
  <div class="blurb-text">
    We can work together today to create an exceptional product that screams to the world, <span class="u-b">I belong to you.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or an inline-block

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1040px;
}

.blurb-text {
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.Jumbotext-1 {
  font-size: 120px;
  line-height: 0.9;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.u-b {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="Jumbotext-1">Deliver a unique experience
    <span class="blurb-text">We can work together today to create an exceptional product that screams to the world, <span class="u-b">I belong to you.</span></span>
  </p>
</div>
```